sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2:The specified module was not found.
python 3.10.1, pip version 24.0, kivy 2.3. When I run the code I get this error.
what could be the solutions to this problem?
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (310, 580)

class LoginPage(MDApp):
    global screen_manager
    screen_manager = ScreenManager()
    def build(self):
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file('main.kv'))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file('signup.kv'))
        return screen_manager
        #return Builder.load_string('login.kv')

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        LoginPage().run()

[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 195 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 1.2.0, git-Unknown, 2024-04-12 (installed at "C:\python3.10.1\lib\site-packages\kivymd\__init__.py")
[WARNING] [KivyMD      ] Version 1.2.0 is deprecated and is no longer supported. Use KivyMD version 2.0.0 from the master branch (pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: Не найден указанный модуль.
  File "C:\python3.10.1\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    mod = importlib.__import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in __import__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\python3.10.1\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

kivy.deps.glew kivy.deps.sdl2, Interestingly, everything  works fine on another computer

Is Kivy installed properly? Can you share your pip -list output?
